# php mysqli_connect weird response

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a very simple create account page. This is the part of the MySQL Database connection:

```
<?php
function dbconnect()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","maistral_quizonline","maistral_kalkas","abcdefghi");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($connection))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        return 0;
    }
    return $connection;
}?>
```

When I try to run dbconnect this is what I get as output:

"Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'maistral_quizonl'@'localhost' (using password: YES)Access denied for user 'maistral'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Now, I'm new to php and maybe i do something really silly, can anyone explain to me this output? Why it seems to try for connection twice and why the connection information is corrupted? What is this: maistral_quizonl? maistral? Why is it cutting the words? And why the first time says that I'm using password and the second time says no? I hope my mistake is not so stupid.

And one other thing. I saw in another post someone suggesting to check if the mysqli_connect function exists so I change this:

```
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
```

to this:

```
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));
```

and the output was this:

"bool(true) Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'maistral_quizonl'@'localhost' (using password: YES)Access denied for user 'maistral'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

lol?
I know that it's pointless to check if mysqli_connect exists after you use it but am I mistaken or isn't the "bool(true)" suppose to print at the and of the line and not the beggining?

What is going on?

Thank you

PS: I have double check that the database exists as well as the user and the priviliges and the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_connect accepts parameters in this order 'host', 'username', 'password', and 'dbname', is this the order in which you have provided your details? It does not seem so.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: I don't know what to say. I can't believe the mistake I did. Two nights in a row I had problems with this page. And I pretty much copy-paste everything and I remember well the time that I placed the name of the database second, It was written somewhere. I don't know. Still stupid of me. Anyway.
Thank you